# Can Delphi programs running in debug mode interact with the IDE's text editor?

Tags: delphi, plugins, vcl

I would like to have a Form in which I could type a number and press a key and then the text editor would scroll down to the code line corresponding to the number I entered. Is this even possible? Is there some sort of API I could use to make such an app? (I don't really want to type a number and scroll down, I just want to know if I can:) If so, would this plugin work for all Delphi versions on one simple code base, or would my code have to contain a lot of `ifs`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write an expert and use the [ToolsAPI](http://www.gexperts.org/open-tools-api-faq/) for this task. I don't think a standalone application can easily achieve this.

Comment: You'd need an expert hosted in the browser and then IPC to communicate between debuggee and expert.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan could you please explain what you mean by browser?

Comment: Yes, that was nonsense. I meant IDE.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan What exactly is an expert? And why is a debugger required? What would you opt for regarding the IPC on Windows? I believe RPC would be best suited in this case.

Comment: @Iccthedral, an *expert* is a plug-in for an Embarcadero IDE. (I.e., *expert* and *plug-in* are synonyms.) The debugger is not required; Goran asked whether what he wants is possible from a "program running in debug mode," but he didn't realize that it's irrelevant whether the debugger happens to be attached to the program he wants to write.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: Yes. All it needs is a second IDE running. We used to do that all day long developing IDE plugins. But NO, you can't do that with the IDE you're actually working with.

It's like the dog chasing its own tail. Looks stupid and is kind of a deadlock.